# How do I stay within governor limits if there is no method which returns the number of Emails sent?

Tags: governorlimits, send-email

I am sending Email alerts to users when importing Accounts, but bulk uploads are failing as the daily limits are being exceeded, or, the number of emails being sent by a single SendEmail call is more than the governor limits. What can be a workaround when I cannot put a condition which will stop further Emails from being sent after governor limits are hit, as I am unable to get the number already sent?

Comment: Are you sending external emails or emails to internal users?

Comment: Internal users.

Comment: Have you tried `Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations()` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_System_Limits_getLimitEmailInvocations)

Comment: That is for the number of calls, and I am calling the method after adding all Emails to a list. So invocations are not the problem. I am invoking just twice.

Comment: @mkorman The question talks about the issue with number of emails sent & not number of email invocations.

Comment: In SingleEmailMessage, if we put Email Ids of Internal Users in a set and add that to setToAddresses, will that be considered as Emails to external or internal users?

Comment: @SagnikChattopadhyay It would be considered as external, that's why you are facing the limits issue. You should use `setTargetObjectId` for sending to internal users

Comment: Yes, apparently that was the case. Thanks guys for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the salesforce docs:

> Using the API or Apex, you can send single emails to a maximum of
>   5,000 external email addresses per day based on Greenwich Mean Time
>   (GMT).
>
> If you use SingleEmailMessage to email your org’s internal users,
>   specifying the user’s ID in setTargetObjectId means the email doesn’t
>   count toward the daily limit. However, specifying internal users’
>   email addresses in setToAddresses means the email does count toward
>   the limit.

So if you are sending emails to internal users you may want to use `setTargetObjectId` of the `SingleEmailMessage` object instance.

Also, I hope you have bulkified your trigger to send all the mails of single transaction at once in the end.

Comment: The trigger is bulkified. But what if I need to insert/update more than 5000 records in a day?

Comment: The 5000 emails per day limit applied if you send emails to external emails or you specify email address while sending emails using SingleEmailMessage. But you are sending emails to internal users, so why not use the setTargetObjectId function and specify the user's Id there? It wont count towards the limit.